How to insert String data as enum into Postgres database in Python
I'm trying to add a String type data into a postgresql database in Python by Prisma. The culumn in database is defined as a specific enum type in Prisma schema. I tried to insert by a String mapping. However the insert was failed with not support with String type. What should I do?
from enum import Enum
from prisma import Prisma

db = Prisma()
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = ''
db.connect()

class DifficultyLevel(Enum):
    EASY = 'EASY'
    MEDIUM = 'MEDIUM'
    HARD = 'HARD'
    LUCK = 'LUCK'

def map_question_difficulty(generated_difficulty):
    difficulty_mapping = {
        'Easy': DifficultyLevel.EASY,
        'Medium': DifficultyLevel.MEDIUM,
        'Hard': DifficultyLevel.HARD,
        'LUCK': DifficultyLevel.LUCK
    }
    return difficulty_mapping.get(generated_difficulty, DifficultyLevel.EASY).value  # Default to EASY if difficulty not found

async def insert_questions_to_db(questions):
    try:
        for question in questions:
            db.elementgenerated.create(
                data={
                    "difficulty": map_question_difficulty(question['difficulty'])
                }
            )
        logging.info(f"Successfully inserted {len(questions)} questions into the database.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error inserting questions into the database: {e}")
        raise

Definition in Prisma schema:
enum DifficultyLevel {
  EASY
  MEDIUM
  HARD
}

Here the Program gave feedback with: 'prisma.errors.DataError: Error converting field "difficulty" of expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "EASY".' The question['difficulty'] is a String object like 'Easy', 'Medium' or 'Hard'.

missing enumerated value
Your prisma schema should also include LUCK.
A discrepancy between python and prisma seems like a Bad Thing.
read the diagnostic

prisma.errors.DataError: Error converting field "difficulty" of expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "EASY".' The question['difficulty'] is a String object like 'Easy', 'Medium' or 'Hard'.

This suggests revising your Enum class to be:
class DifficultyLevel(Enum):
    EASY = 'Easy'
    MEDIUM = 'Medium'
    HARD = 'Hard'
    LUCK = 'Luck'

auto()
Side note: consider DRYing up the class by defining it this way:
from enum import Enum, auto

class DifficultyLevel(Enum):
    EASY = auto()
    MEDIUM = auto()
    HARD = auto()
    LUCK = auto()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.title()

And then use f-string or str() rather than .value.

Thank you for the help! Actually, I just noticed that its just a dumb mistake (The database was init by docker but I only updated in local env. But, thanks for the help and I will learn about the auto()!
